# Does a change in standard deviation have any effect on correlation, all other things being equal?

Tags: correlation, standard-deviation

All things being equal, when looking at the correlation between two variables, a greater standard deviation in one variable is linked to lower R squared.  However, is a greater standard deviation in one variable linked to any change in correlation itself?

Comment: You need to specify exactly what you mean by "all things". Clearly, you can't have them all equal when variance changes. Does covariance change in your scenario, e.g.?

Comment: "all other things being equal" is not really possible and it's not at all clear what you really do mean to ask. Please specify what happens to the random variable (or variables) to allow the standard deviation to change.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what exactly you mean by "a change in standard deviation."  Suppose you have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$.  You are interested in their correlation, \begin{equation*}\mathrm{Corr}[X, Y] \equiv \frac{\mathrm{Cov}[X, Y]}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}[X]\mathrm{Var}[Y]}}.\end{equation*}

Suppose you change $X$ by multiplying it by a scalar $\alpha$ (a change of units from meters to feet, for example, or from minutes to seconds). This changes the standard deviation: $\mathrm{Var}[\alpha X]^{0.5} = \alpha \, \mathrm{Var}[X]^{0.5}$, i.e. the standard deviation is multiplied by $\alpha$. However, the covariance and the variance will change in a way that keeps the correlation constant: \begin{equation*}\mathrm{Corr}[\alpha X, Y] = \frac{\mathrm{Cov}[\alpha X, Y]}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}[\alpha X]\mathrm{Var}[Y]}} = \mathrm{Corr}[X, Y].\end{equation*}

Here's a little example in R:

```
x <- rnorm(10^3, mean=9, sd=7)
y <- rpois(10^3, lambda=12)
cor(x, y)
cor(10*x, y)  # Same correlation!
sd(x)
sd(10*x)  # Larger std dev
```

Comment: If you multiply $X$ by a scalar, the "all things being equal" hypothesis doesn't hold because $\mathbb{E}[X]$ changes as well. I think what the OP's hypothesis can be interpreted as: $\mathbb{E}[X]$ doesn't change, only $Var(X)$ changes.

Comment: True, but the OP doesn't state precisely what is held equal.

Answer (score 2):

For two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, their (Pearson) correlation is given by

$\rho_{XY}=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}$

As you said, all others things being equals, if $Var(X)$ increase then $\rho_{XY}$ decreases. Same thing for $Var(Y)$, so it is a reversed relation. For $Cov(X,Y)$, it is a direct relation, $\rho_{XY}$ increases as $Cov(X,Y)$ increases.

I talk about variance, but it is just the squared value of the standard deviation. Hence, the logic is the same.

For completeness' sake, from @Matemattica comment, here is an example in R

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 <- rnorm(100, 0, 2)
x2 <- rnorm(100, 0, 2)
cov(x1,x2)

set.seed(1234)
x1 <- rnorm(100, 0, 2)
x3 <- rnorm(100, 0, 4)
cov(x1,x3)
```

$Cov(x1,x2) = -0.1052611$

$Cov(x1,x3) = -0.2105222$

As we can see, the change in variance also affect the covariance between the variables. So by changing the variance of a variable, the "all others things equal" doesn't stand as it may be intended.

In this particular case, we compute the $\rho$

```
cov(x1,x2) / (2 * 2) # rho
cov(x1,x3) / (2 * 4) # rho
```

and they are equals.

Comment: You didn't take into account the change in $Cov(X,Y)$ when $Var(X)$ changes

Comment: Ha ha, yes, it all depends on what the meaning (scope) of "all other things being equal" is.

Comment: @Matemattica True. From the question, I assume another variable with the same covariance (all other things equal) and only a differente variance.